# not showing anything in network tab and console.log("posted successfully")

Tags: angularjs, node.js, console.log

Front-end

```
customer.controller("new_info", 
  function($scope, $routeParams,$http)
  {    
    $scope.customer = {};
    $scope.register = function () {
      $http.post('localhost:4000/new_info', $scope.customer).then(
        function (response) { 
          console.log("posted successfully");
        }
    );
  }
});
```

Back-end

```
 app.post('/new_info',(req,res)=>{ console.log(req.body); });
```

Comment: Somebody help me

Comment: What is the problem here? What do you want to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I want to show the things in console window  after hitting submit button . And when I hit the submit button nothing comes up in the network tab and the console window .

Comment: Can you post your template code with the "submit button"?

Comment: https://github.com/ChiragMittal/posting .

Comment: Handing users a link and expecting users to debug the code is unlikely to get a question and answer that is useful to other readers. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  **in the question itself.**